# Regex for dropping http:// and www. from URLs

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a bunch of urls like these.

```
  $urls = array(
    'https://site1.com',
    'https://www.site2.com',
    'http://www.site3.com',
    'https://site4.com',
    'site5.com',
    'www.site6.com',
    'www.site7.co.uk',
    'site8.tk'
  );
```

I wanted to remove the http, https, :// and www. from these strings so that the output will look like these.

```
  $urls = array(
    'site1.com',
    'site2.com',
    'site3.com',
    'site4.com',
    'site5.com',
    'site6.com',
    'site7.co.uk',
    'site8.tk'
  );
```

I came up with this solution.

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
   $pattern = '/(http[s]?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/i';
   $replace = "";
   echo "before: $url after: ".preg_replace('/\/$/', '', preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $url))."\n";
}
```

I was wondering how I could avoid the second preg_replace. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

preg_replace can also take an array, so you don't even need the loop. You can do this with a one liner:

```
$urls = preg_replace('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '$1', $urls);
```

Comment: Thanks for the bounty PaulPRO, I just didn't exactly understand why. Your answer is perfect.

Comment: This should do the same: `$urls = preg_replace('~^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?~i', '', $urls);`.

Comment: @paulpro is this working with both http and https ?

Comment: @Azzo Yes, the `?` makes the `s` optional.

Answer (score 13):

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)\/$/i
```

And use what's on `$3`. Or, even better, change the first two parentheses to the non-capturing version `(?:)` and use what's on 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly it is you want to do, it might be better to stick with PHP's own URL parsing facilities, namely [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
foreach ($urls as &$url) {
    $url = preg_replace('~^www.~', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
}
unset($url);
```

`parse_url` will give you the host of the URL, even if it will contain a port number or HTTP authentication data. (Whether this is what you need, depends on your exact use case though.)

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

```
$urls = preg_replace('~^(?:https?://)?(?:www[.])?~i', '', $urls);
```