# trimming www. and http:// best practices

Tags: php, trim

my code works, i just want to know if its a bad practise, because i suppose so. Ive tryed all the preg_replace but it didnt seem to work. So i just wrote it like this.

As an imput I expect url

> google.com  www.google.com http://google.com
>
> or
>
> http://www.google.com

as a result I need

google.com

my code:

```
 $website = trim($website); //removes space characters
                        $website = trim($website, '/');
                        $website = trim($website, 'http://');
                        $website = trim($website, 'www.');
```

Comment: So you want to strip the whole `http://www.` from it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738752/regex-for-dropping-http-and-www-from-urls

Comment: Contrary to popular believe (esp. among Management) the `www.` string is not the standard protocol prefix for web sites. That'd be `http:` and `https:`. Stripping www blindly can eventually just break the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way `trim` works is that it trims each individual character (`www.` is the same as `.w`).

You're looking for `preg_replace` with a regex of `^(https?://)?(www\.)?`:

```
$website = preg_replace('~^(https?://)?(www\.)?~i', '', $website);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VwsNmRmuwjV4c-Qm)

**Autopsy**:

- `^` the match MUST start with whatever comes after this (makes sure that we only replace if the match is in the start)
- `(https?://)?`

  - `http` - the literal string `http`
  - `s?` - an optional `s` (in case we use `https`)
  - `://` - the literal string `://`
  - `?` - makes the whole thing optional
- `(www\.)?`

  - `www\.` - the literal string `www.` (you need to escape the `.` to `\.` as `.` means "any character")
  - `?` - makes the whole thing optional
- `i` - this is the modifier, and `i` makes the whole thing in case sensitive (will match HTTP and http)

[**Regex 101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lM7nX1)

Comment: wow, really well explained. Thank you. It works :)

Answer (score 2):

KIS: Keep It Simple.

http://www.php.net/parse_url

From the docs:

```php
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

EDIT:
[PHP Getting Domain Name From Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain) When you have the host.

Comment: Even if you used `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)` (I have no clue why you use `path`), you'd still get `www.google.com` which is not what OP wants. [DEMO](http://codepad.org/ETWsQ4yQ).

Comment: But it's a lot easier to obtain the actual domain from this.

Answer (score 0):

Classic use case for RegEx. This snippet removes http(s) and www prefixes.

> $new_url = preg_replace('/(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(.*)/?$/i', '$1',
>   $url);