# Add regex rule to remove "www." on existing expression

Tags: javascript, regex

With the help [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498629/1417223) I'm getting clean domain names from urls in strings, like the following:

```
url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"  
var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);  
return matches ? matches[1] : url;
>> "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

I would like to remove the subdomain "www" (and the following dot) as well though, if existing. How would I change the above expression to accomplish this?

Comment: A simple `.replace("www.","")` would work just fine.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738752/regex-for-dropping-http-and-www-from-urls

Comment: @JorgeCampos That would cause trouble when the string "www." appears in a different context. Like in `http://example.com/mythoughtsaboutthewww.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match optional `www.` after `http://`:

```
var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
//=> ["http://www.stackoverflow.com/", "stackoverflow.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"  
var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/(www\.)?([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);  
return matches ? matches[2] : url;
```

to support url addresses with and without `www.`