# Remove http:// and www from form field while customer is typing, and show alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in which is a field (#domain).

Here I want the customer to add their own domain name. Often I see that they input wrong, even thought the instructions are short and clear.

To make it more user friendly, and to avoid errors - I'd like to add a validator or auto corrector.

This is a jquery and bootstrap environment.

**This is the solution I have made for now:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/ew1qoky9/1/

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="input your domain (WITHOUT http:// and www.)" class="form-control" name="domain" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="domain" style="max-width:320px">
</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
$('#domain').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

This removes all special caracters and spaces on the fly. However without telling the customer.

Customers still input http:// and http://www. - and I'd like to auto-remove these too.

**Can I add something in the regex or js to make this happen?** - Or what is a suggested working solution?

**Is there a way to show a message/ alert if the customer enters a special caracter?** Like "Please use only a-z, 0-9 and dots. If your domain has special caracters, please enter the ACE-version of your domain name." - Either a bootstrap alarm, or a standard js alert?

PS: I found this: [Regex for dropping http:// and www. from URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738752/regex-for-dropping-http-and-www-from-urls) about removing the above from urls, but I don't understand how to use this in my code. I am very thankful for suggestions. Please play with the fiddle :-)

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$");`

Comment: You can still copy and paste special characters in the box https://i.gyazo.com/c8ffe3d3832179f0358520510610f499.gif

Comment: Just an observation - why shouldn't you enter `www`?  It's only by convention that `www.example.com` and `example.com` are _usually_ the same, but they _could_ be entirely different things.

Comment: *Aside:* You should not be putting in long help messages for the placeholder attribute. Ideally it should be like `<input placeholder='example.com'...`. A short simple and direct input *hint*.

Comment: Hi James, it has to do with the way the server handles the domain name. It is used as an account name and not as a domain name. The customer later chooses if he/ she wants to use www or not.

Comment: Hi @Abhitalks, I did this as customers still input www etc. That is soon history :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your code, user cannot type special characters like `://` but user can paste it. To handle such cases, you can validate it on `blur` event. Following is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ew1qoky9/3/) depicting same. Also I have added a simple check for`"http"`, and will show error if http is entered. You can configure per your requirement.

#### Code

```js
(function() {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+$");
  $('#domain').keypress(function(e) {
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
    }

    $("#lblError").text("Please use only a-z, 0-9 and dots.").fadeIn();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });

  $("#domain").on("blur", function(e) {
    var str = $(this).val();
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      if (str.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
        $("#lblError").text("Domain name cannot have HTTP in it.").fadeIn();
        return false;
      }
      $("#lblError").fadeOut();
    } else {
      $("#lblError").text("Please use only a-z, 0-9 and dots.").fadeIn();
      return false
    }
  });
})()
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input placeholder="input your domain (WITHOUT http:// and www.)" class="form-control" name="domain" type="text" autocomplete="off" id="domain" style="max-width:320px">
  <p class="error" id="lblError"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This looks elegant. Am testing now :-)

Comment: This worked wonderful. I removed the A-Z in the regex, as I need only a-z After doing that I got some problems using an iPad, until I thought about the iPad defaults to use capital letters in first capital. I added autocapitalize="off" to the input tag, and now it works flawless :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$('#domain').on('input', function() {
  rawInput = $(this).val();
  console.log(rawInput);
  cleanInput = rawInput.replace('www.', '');
  cleanInput = cleanInput.replace('http://', '');
  cleanInput = cleanInput.replace('https://', '');
  console.log(cleanInput);
  $(this).val(cleanInput);
});
```

See it in action here:
https://jsbin.com/birunuyeso/edit?html,js,console,output

Look at your JavaScript console and you'll see what it's doing. In production you can obviously remove any of the lines that use `console.log()`.